# Does getting killed by a woman affect eligibility for 72 houris?

Tags: sunni, islamic-basis, jannah

From [Isil fanatics 'fear being killed by a woman will deprive them of virgins in paradise'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/iraq/11110724/Isil-fanatics-fear-being-killed-by-a-woman-will-deprive-them-of-virgins-in-paradise.html)

> The increasing number of female soldiers taking to the front line
>   against extremists of the Islamic State in Iraq and the Levant (Isil)
>   is sowing fear in their ranks that they will be denied their prize in
>   paradise, according to Ed Royce, who chairs the US House International
>   Relations Committee.
>
> "These Isil soldiers apparently believed that if they were killed in
>   battle, they went to paradise as long as they were killed by a man,"
>   he told The New York Post, citing reporters of Kurdish female fighters
>   laughing as they repelled attacks by the extremist group.

This sounds somewhat unlikely, though I could imagine some specific wording mentioning martyrs getting killed by men, and therefore not applying if they get killed by women.

Does martyrs getting killed by a woman affect eligibility for 72 houris, especially in the Sunni view of Islam?

Comment: No such thing, plus we don't know whether these people are considered martyrs or not, God knows best, they kill innocent people and don't follow Islamic guidlines!!, i dont know if you reed this in the news or not, that people travelling from Britain are contacting their home land wanting to quit but afraid of getting jailed because they are forced to perform the unexpected!! plus men and women are equal in Islam!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ridiculous and untrue, at least in mainstream Sunni Islam. As far as I'm aware, the ahadith that talk about martyrs (those killed fighting in a legitimate military engagement) all talk about them in a passive sense without reference to who killed them. For example, look through here: http://sunnah.com/search/martyr

There is something very perverted about whatever these people are following, this is probably the least of it. This happens when you don't know anything about Islam and want to fight for other reasons but try to cloak your motivations in a religious garb.